# Memory leak in nodejs in simple function calling

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

Edited Question

I was trying to understand why there is memory leak in simple function call. why node does not release memory as local scope is ended.

Thanks in advance

```
function somefunction()
{
    var n = 20000;
    var x  ={};
    for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
        x['some'+i] = {"abc" : ("abc@yxy.com"+i)};
    }

}

// Memory Leak
var init = process.memoryUsage();
somefunction();
var end = process.memoryUsage();
console.log("memory consumed 2nd Call : "+((end.rss-init.rss)/1024)+" KB");
```

Answer (score 1):

PREVIOUS ANSWER before the question was edited to correct a code error:

The results are invalid because this code doesn't invoke the function:

```
(function(){
    somefunction();
});
```

The anonymous function is declared but not invoked. So it does not use much in the way of resources.

You need to invoke the function:

```
(function(){
    somefunction();
}());
```

Comment: I edited my question, basically I was trying to find why it consumes memory, it should release memory, as execution exits from local scope

Comment: The V8 engine frees up heap memory whenever it wants to, basically. If you want to force the GC, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766753/nodejs-socket-io-simple-code-memory-leak/30786603#30786603

Answer (score 0):

@Mohit, Both strategy taking same memory consumption. Run each code separately and check by yourself.

EDIT: 
Wait for gc. When gc will call then memory should be free. Try to call gc explicitly then check it.

Comment: I edited my question, basically I was trying to find why it consumes memory, it should release memory, as execution exits from local scope